# Make progress bar display download status

Tags: c#

I am making a winform program that can download updates.

I am trying to make a progressbar that shows the status of the download. I wrote the exact same as all others i saw 
(diffrent download url ofcourse: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/.../update.xml?token_hash=SOME_HASH&dl=1)

I suppose its the correct link to use, since its the direct download link.

I dont know if this is important, but the form that downloads the update.xml file, is not my main form. Other people i saw, wrote the code it in the main form. My main form has a "check for updates" button, and that button opens the update form.

I am using: System.Net and all default "usings" when you create a winform form.

```
public partial class Update : Form
{
    public Update()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Update_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
        client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
        client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
        client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/.../update.xml?token_hash=...&dl=1"), desktop);
    }

    void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Maximum = (int)e.TotalBytesToReceive / 100;
        progressBar1.Value = (int)e.BytesReceived / 100;
    }

    void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        label2.Text = "Download Completed";
    }
}
```

This is taken from somone who made it work, but it still don't work for me! (Programming in a nutshell :D)

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

EDIT: I am sorry that i wasn't clear enought before. The file didn't even download, thats the problem. But it is fixed now anyways.

I will keep that in mind if i should need more help.

Comment: You shouldn't include real credentials in sample code (like the `token_hash` query parameter in `client.DownloadFileAsync` call).

Comment: @OndrejTucny, though it is true, but offtopic, :)

Comment: "It doesn't work" is entirely unhelpful.  What doesn't work?  Do you get an exception, does nothing happen, is it not updating until it's all done, or what?  Describe what is happening in detail along with what should be happening instead.

Comment: @David Which is why it's not posted as an answer.  It's a perfectly appropriate comment to make.

Comment: Deleted what was my answer, as it was not going to be complete.  I don't understand what the failure is, so can't answer completely without more information.

Comment: How big is `update.xml`? If it's a fairly small file (which I suspect) the `DownloadProgressChanged` event may not even fire.

Comment: Why divide the total bytes to receive by 100 in the progress bar? Try `progressBar1.Maximum = 100; progressBar1.Value = (int)((100* e.BytesReceived)/e.TotalBytesToReceive);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your DownloadFileAsync command line with:

```
 client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://download.thinkbroadband.com/10MB.zip"), desktop + "test.zip");
```

...and see if that helps.

Comment: The zip file was damaged, but the xml file worked just fine.       Thank you for that!

Comment: The problem was that i needed to write a name for the downloaded file and what format it was.

Comment: Yeah, if you look at the last paragraph of the: http://www.thinkbroadband.com/download.html you'll see that it's fake zip file for testing purposes. I just wanted to show you the way to fix your code ;)